# php DOMDocument getAttribute

Tags: php, rss, domdocument

I am using the php `DOMDocument` to parse through an RSS 2.0 feed. Everything is working fine except for this line.

```
$image = $node->getElementsByTagName('itunes:image')->item(0)->getAttribute('href');
```

Where `$node` is the `<item>` element.

`$image` is empty after the function.

**Edit:**

The following is also returning empty...

```
$node->getElementsByTagName('itunes:summary')->item(0)->nodeValue
```

So does this have something to do with the `:` in the node name?

Comment: So what you need to know is how to get the namespaced `<itunes:image>` nodes?

Comment: I guess, I just noticed that another node with a `:` is also returning empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learn about [namespaces](http://zvon.org/comp/r/tut-Namespace.html), and use [`getElementsByTagNameNS`](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getelementsbytagnamens.php).

```
$node->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd', 'summary');
```